# Mysql select query if condition parameter is null then ignore the parameter

Tags: mysql

I have the following condition **(m.idAgent = agent OR agent is null)**. It simply returns me all agents if i pass null to agent param.
But how can i achieve the same thing in **MYSQL**.

I.e if i pass null then that part of the where condition should be ignored and only the other conditions which are not null should be considered.

Comment: Is that not a MySQL condition? It's exactly what you need.

Comment: @Nick i want a query where if my condition parameter is null then that part of the where condition should be ignored and rest of the not null parameter should be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE` as follows:

```
WHERE COALESCE(agent, m.idAgent) = m.idAgent
```

This should work because when `agent` is `NULL`, it would just be replaced with the RHS of the comparison, and therefore would always pass.  I presume that the following is actually what your code looks like:

```
WHERE COALESCE(?, m.idAgent) = m.idAgent
```

Here the `?` is a placeholder for a value to be bound in the statement.